# iScroll sensitivity

Tags: iscroll4

Im using the latest iscroll script for a site viewed on an ipad. It works but you have to pressed down and scroll slowly for it to scroll properly. Is there anything I can change in the iscroll script or settings that would allow for better sensitivity to the touch and the scrolling itself is faster?

Comment: Is this site public? I have a lot of experience using iScroll, so I might take a look at it.

Comment: @Guillaume Schuermans No its not public and I cant give access to it. I tried your suggestions but still the problem persists. The thing scrolls, the problem is you have to be deliberate with your finger movement. Otherwise if you try to just quickly swipe up or down with your finger it doesnt move at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit hard to really suggest the solution. But here are some pointers.

Attach the global touchmove event (and prevent defaultbehavior).

```
document.attachEvent('touchmove', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

Keep the html elements inside the scroller to a minimum.
You can add -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) to force the elements through the hardware acceleraion.